# error (1064) while creating table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql db(version 5.5) and using mysql query browser(v 1.1.5) .But when i try to create a simple table using query browser am getting following error:

```
CREATE TABLE `tstaks`.`employee` (
  `empid` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`empid`)
)
TYPE = InnoDB;


mysql error no 1064
you have an error in your sql sytax,check the manual that corresponds to your mysqlserver version for right syntax to use
near type ='innoDB
```

Answer (score 4):

`TYPE` needs to be `ENGINE`: `ENGINE=InnoDB`

Comment: @Peter Kruithofunder table oprion of mysql query browser i have engine == innodb sorrage engine selected

Comment: I don't know about mysql query browser. I just know the actual SQL you provided needs to have this change. Maybe mysql query browser is generating invalid SQL.

Comment: i have pasetd the sql generated by mysql query browser in my orignial post.Where do i select engine == innodb in mysql?

Comment: Why don't you try PhpMyAdmin (http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)? It's great for managing your database, or just execute the raw sql in the mysql command line.